# Javascript: Using .sort with compare function to find longest word in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting, compare

I am a beginner student in Javascript. I have been puzzling over this problem for the last few hours, so I'm hoping that somebody can help me with the the logic in the code I'm trying to write.

I am currently trying to write a function that will take the longest string in an array and pass it back to the console. If there is a tie, the console should return the first word with the most letters.

I found a good piece of code that will do this, but I can't find a way to make it into a function.

```
arr. sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length })[0];
```

I tried

```
var longestWord = function(arr) {
    sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length })[0];
}
```

This doesn't work. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what it is. Also, I can't *quite* grasp why exactly this words. I can can understand that the function compares the lengths of the two variables, but why does the 0 index have to be at the end?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Just a side note: sort is an expensive way to do this since even the best case it's O(nlog n). It's better to just iterate through the array with a for loop and compare each word with a `longestWordFound` variable which would be O(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var my_array = ["a", "aaa", "aa", "aaaaaaa", "a"];
function longestString(arr) {
  return arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
  })[0];
}
longestString(my_array);
```

I would suggest use to read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
before you use sort(). Make sure you understand the irator before using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your advice!

Answer (score 3):

Your function returns nothing. Also, you call `sort` function, but not `Array.prototype.sort`.

This one does work:

```js
var longestWord = function(arr) {
  return arr.sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length })[0];
}

document.body.innerText = longestWord(['a', 'ab', 'abcdef', 'abcd', 'a', 'abcde']); // abcdef
```

Answering your "but why does the 0 index have to be at the end" question: `Array.prototype.sort` returns an array, and you get the first item in an array in order to get the longest word. This `[0]` is an array subscript, i.e. "first item in an array".

These two snippets are *equivalent*:

```
var arr = ['a', 'ab', 'abcdef', 'abcd', 'a', 'abcde']; 
// arr is ['a', 'ab', 'abcdef', 'abcd', 'a', 'abcde']

var arrSorted = arr.sort(function(a, b) { return b.length - a.length; });
// arrSorted is ['abcdef', 'abcde', 'abcd', 'ab', 'a', 'a']

var result = arrSorted[0];
// result is abcdef, the longest word
```

and

```
var arr = ['a', 'ab', 'abcdef', 'abcd', 'a', 'abcde']; 
// arr is ['a', 'ab', 'abcdef', 'abcd', 'a', 'abcde']

var result = arr.sort(function(a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })[0];
// result is abcdef, the longest word
```

The difference is that the second one doesn't store the intermediate result in a variable.

Comment: For some reason I thought that `.sort` does not return the same object, my fault.

Comment: Thank you so much! this really helped me understand why my code wasn't working.